# Solr throwing 'org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException' on Start

Tags: apache, exception, solr

I am setting up Solr for Centos 7. When i try to execute any sample project for ex. using `./bin/solr start -e techproducts, its throwing error of 'Exception : org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)'` . How to fix this. Java is installed under '/usr/bin/java'

I tried with changing Java home directory path

```
./bin/solr start -e techproducts

*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 31165.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
```

Solr home directory /tmp/solr-7.7.2/example/techproducts/solr already exists.

Starting up Solr on port 8983 using command:

```
"bin/solr" start -p 8983 -s "example/techproducts/solr"

*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 31165.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
WARNING: Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting.

     Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this check, start with argument '-force'

ERROR: Failed to start Solr using command: "bin/solr" start -p 8983 -s "example/techproducts/solr" Exception : org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

Comment: `WARNING: Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting. Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this check, start with argument '-force'`?

Answer (score 2):

Credit for the answer should go to @MatsLindh (see comment above). I'm adding it here for others who may experience the same problem.

The issue is that Solr doesn't want you to run it as a root user - or what it thinks is a root user (I've seen this issue with WSL as well and one isn't running as root).

Using root is a security risk but you can force Solr to start anyways by adding `-force` to the command, for example:

`bin/solr start -e cloud -force`

Comment: In my case (solr 9 on ubuntu) still got an error with -force that it didn't have permissions to create the logs directory:  `ERROR: Logs directory /opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr/../logs could not be created.` So, I had to run as double root: `sudo bin/solr start -e cloud -force` - maybe my ubuntu permissions are borked...?